getSlicerState() is not working for SelectAll option
We are facing issue when using Power BI API getSlicerState().
When we select "Select All" value in the slicer it returns us an error.
Below is the screenshot depicting the same.
enter image description here
Error message text:
message: 'slicerSerializationFailed',
detailedMessage: 'Failed to serialize slicer filters to json object', level: 3}
detailedMessage: "Failed to serialize slicer filters to json object"level: 3
message: "slicerSerializationFailed"[[Prototype]]: Object 'The promise was rejected '
Tried getSlicerState function.
I was expecting an array of all values, or a "Select All" string but got an error instead.

Select all doesn't mean that we select everything in slicer. It means that selected items become unselected.
When you select “Select All” in a slicer, Power BI does not return all the individual items in the slicer state. Instead, it returns an empty filter because “Select All” is equivalent to applying no filter at all.
For more information you can refer to this documentation:
Slicers in Power BI - Power BI | Microsoft Learn
